# Email settings for sending email in PHP through custom domain on gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail

I have a custom domain setup on gmail for mail.

I have hosted my website on a different hosting provider and I'm using CodeIgniter and PHP to send an email through my account.

What are the settings I need to enable sending mail (from a contact form) through my gmail account?
And what code do I need to use?

Update:
What I've tried is the following:
- Create a new email account (@gmail.com, not custom)
- Enable 2 step verification
- Generated an app-specific password
- Used this to send the email
Even this is not working.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'samesenderaccount@gmail.com';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'appspecificpassword';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;   

$mail->From = 'samesenderaccount@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->AddAddress('samesenderaccount@gmail.com', 'Info');  // Add a recipient
//$mail->AddAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->AddReplyTo('other@gmail.com', 'From Try');
//$mail->AddCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->AddBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
                                // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body in bold!';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following format to send an e mail in php codeigniter. 
You might find the values to change from the provider.

```
public function sendMail()
{
      $config = Array(
     'protocol' => 'smtp',
     'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
     'smtp_port' => 465,
     'smtp_user' => 'axxx@gmail.com', // change it to yours
     'smtp_pass' => '*******', // change it to yours
     'mailtype' => 'html',
     'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
     'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );


     $this->load->library('email', $config);
     $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
     $this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com'); // change it to yours
     $this->email->to('yyy@gmail.com');// change it to yours
     $this->email->subject('Subject');// change it to yours
     $this->email->message('message');// change it to yours

     if($this->email->send())
    {
      //success message
    }
    else
   {
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
   }
}
```

You can use variables and pass email, subject, message etc.

Comment: I'm using a custom domain. Also gmail doesn't allow to send mail like this anymore.